# Reuse form's inputs in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've used this method of form in ionic :

When I fill out the form and submit them, the new slide appears but if I restart the app, Everything goes back to the first. 
How can I fix this? I wanna save this inputs in slides to use them again ...

some parts of the code:

**.html:**

```html
<ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title text-center class="persian pdtop" > <ion-icon name = '{{slide.icon}}'> </ion-icon> {{slide.ttl}}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
    <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
    <h2 class="slide-title persian2" [innerHTML]="slide.title"></h2>
    <p class="persian" [innerHTML]="slide.description"></p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-slide>
<form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Title</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>    
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Icon</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="icon"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>    
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Header</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="ttl"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>    
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>image</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="image"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!todo.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**.ts:**

```
// ...
export class HomePage {
  private todo : FormGroup;
  constructor(public nav: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
      icon: [''],
      ttl: [''],
      image: [''],
    });
  }

  logForm(){
    console.log(this.todo.value);
    this.slides.push(this.todo.value);
  }

  slides = [
    {
      title: "HBD",
      description: "The <b>Ionic Component Documentation</b> showcases a number of useful components that are included out of the box with Ionic.",
      image: "",
      ttl: "no.1",
      icon: "heart",
    },
    {
      title: "What is Ionic?",
      description: "<b>Ionic Framework</b> is an open source SDK that enables developers to build high quality mobile apps with web technologies like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.",
      image: "",
      ttl: "my love",
      icon: "heart",
    }
  ];
}

//...
```

When I fill out the form and submit them, the new slide appears but if I restart the app, Everything goes back to the first. 
How can I fix this? I wanna save this inputs in slides to use them again ...

Answer (score 0):

Every time your app is restarted, the Slides component is initialized again, and this component is always initialized in the first slide by default (index=0).

First you should save (in your DB, in the LocalStorage, in a provider, etc.) the index of the slide that you want to keep. For that you could use the method **getActiveIndex()** every time you change a slide.

If you want to initialize the Slides component in a specific slide (the one that you have saved, for example), you can use the property: **initialSlide**, and set it with the index number of the slide you want.

For example, if you want to initialize the Slides component in the slide with index=2, you should use it like this:

```
<ion-slides intitialSlide="2">
  <ion-slide>
  </ion-slide>
<ion-slides>
```

For more information about the Slides component, i recommend to read the official Ionic Documentation about this.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides

I hope it will help you to solve your problem.